# How can I grep for multiple patterns at once?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am looking for two separate patterns each having a specific constraints within some large compressed files. I can't for the life of me figure out how to grep for both cases at once.

For an example, a file daily records that add up over time:

myfile

```
AnimalID-Type-Mood

Animal456-Dog-happy-day1
Animal453-Elephant-happy-day1
Animal896-Dog-sad-day1
Animal405-Dog-angry-day1
Animal443-Goat-angry-day1
Animal453-Dog-sad-day1
Animal473-Cat-sad-day1
Animal452-cat-happy-day1
Animal456-Dog-angry-day2
Animal453-Elephant-sad-day2
Animal896-Dog-happy-day2
Animal405-Dog-angry-day2
Animal443-Goat-happy-day2
Animal453-Dog-happy-day2
Animal473-Cat-happy-day2
Animal452-cat-happy-day2
```

So far I have tried

```
zcat.myfile | grep -e  'Dog|happy' | grep -e 'Cat|happy'
```

Essentially I am trying to find how many days out of the year, by AnimalID, that a dog is happy and a cat is happy. I can do counts and sorts, I just can't figure out how to run that

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zgrep` here:

```
zgrep -iE '(Dog|Cat)-happy' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the `-i` hint! nice catch! ;) however, I think `-E` is not necessary...

Comment: `-E` just allows you to use extended regexes which means fewer backslashes.

Comment: Yes that's right. Without `-E` it will be: `zgrep -i '\(Dog\|Cat\)-happy' file`

Comment: @glennjackman Nice article, a good reference in some situations! (and a nice term) Do you know whether `-E` is supported across all platforms? (Because then it would really making no sense not using `-E` if the pattern could by simplyfied through that). I only know that `sed -r ` isn't supported across all platforms and that's why I've learned to love backslashes on SO...

Comment: Well, [GNU](https://gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html) (and presumably BSD), and [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/grep-1.html#scrolltoc) (in /usr/xpg4/bin/grep) all do. **All** platforms? Who knows?

Comment: @glennjackman I should have said *all* platforms. :) thanks for your input!

Comment: OSX sed uses -E, and GNU silently supports that too.

Comment: my GNU sed manpage don't mention `-E`. You mean `-E` will silently being handled as `-r`? (Would being nice for portability)

Comment: `grep -E` is specified by [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), so it *should* be available in any `grep`. (You can also use `egrep`, although that is officially deprecated. Says Posix: "The old egrep and fgrep commands are likely to be supported for many years to come as implementation extensions, allowing historical applications to operate unmodified.") `sed` is a different story.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify multiple pattern with the `-e` option

```
$ seq 10 | grep -e 5 -e 6
5
6
```

Comment: short and expressive!

Answer (score 2):

It's `egrep` or `grep -E` for extended regular expression with alteration using `(a|b)` for a or b. Note capital E.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a basic regex:

```
grep -i '\(Dog\|Cat\)-happy' input
```